# ¿Cómó hago para que sed me sustituya un texto una única vez?

Tags: sed

Yo tengo esta sentencia en el archivo xxx.txt:

```
select camp1,camp2,campN from pricing_user.prc_pvp a join ( select werks, matnr, pvp_category_type, max(start_date) as recent_date from pricing_user.prc_pvp where werks = "0006" and pvp_category_type in (1,3) group by 1,2,3 ) b on a.matnr = b.matnr and a.werks = b.werks and a.pvp_category_type=b.pvp_category_type where recent_date = start_date
```

Si quiero saber cuántos registros me va a dar esa consulta, solo hago:

```
select count(*) from pricing_user.prc_pvp a join ( select werks, matnr, pvp_category_type, max(start_date) as recent_date from pricing_user.prc_pvp where werks = "0006" and pvp_category_type in (1,3) group by 1,2,3 ) b on a.matnr = b.matnr and a.werks = b.werks and a.pvp_category_type=b.pvp_category_type where recent_date = start_date
```

Este tipo de tarea lo hago muy repetitivo y quiero automatizarlo, pero para eso, tendría que cambiar todos los campos `camp1, camp2,....campN` por `count(*)`.

El problema es que no lo logro hacer . Estoy haciendo esto:

```
sed -i 's/select/select count\(\*\);/g' xxx.txt|sed 's/from/;from/g' |awk -F";" '{print $1 " " $3}'
```

Pero la salida es:

```
select count(*) from pricing_user.prc_pvp a join ( select count(*)
```

y lo que quiero es:

```
select count(*) from pricing_user.prc_pvp a join ( select werks, matnr, pvp_category_type, max(start_date) as recent_date from pricing_user.prc_pvp where werks = "0006" and pvp_category_type in (1,3) group by 1,2,3 ) b on a.matnr = b.matnr and a.werks = b.werks and a.pvp_category_type=b.pvp_category_type where recent_date = start_date
```

Answer (score 3):

Ya vi cómo resolverlo: hago que  `sed` no sea global

```
sed -i 's/select/select count\(\*\);/' xxx.txt|sed 's/from/;from/' |awk -F";" '{print $1 " " $3}'
```

---

Es decir, en lugar de decir `sed 's/busco/sustituyo/g'`, hago `sed 's/busco/sustituyo/` (sin la `g` final) para que haga la sustitución una única vez.

```
$ echo "2 3 2 4" | sed 's/2/XX/'
XX 3 2 4  # el "2" se ha sustituido una única vez

$ echo "2 3 2 4" | sed 's/2/XX/g'
#                              ^
XX 3 XX 4  # el "2" se ha sustituido múltiples veces
```